# How to programmatically update subject schema and compatibility in Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, kafka-python, confluent-kafka-python

I have a schema already registered in schema registry, which I was able to do using `register()` like this,

```
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient, schema

subject_name = "new-schema"
schema_url = "https://{{ schemaRegistry }}:8081" 
sr = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_url)

schema = schema.AvroSchema({
    "namespace": "example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "user",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "fname", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": "int"}
    ]
})

my_schema = sr.register(subject_name, schema)
```

Now I need to update this same subject with a new field, so I will get new schema id, and `version = 2`.

```
updated_schema = schema.AvroSchema({
    "namespace": "example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "user",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "fname", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": "int"},
        {"name": "favorite_food",  "type": "string"}
    ]
})
```

I tried using `sr.register(subject_name, updated_schema)`, it throws error for same subject:

```
AttributeError: 'ClientError' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
ClientError: Incompatible Avro schema
```

Yes this function is to register new schema not to update. I didn't get any update function and I don't know how can I do this. SO how can I update schema? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the full error trace?

Comment: I am getting, 
AttributeError: 'ClientError' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' ,         
ClientError: Incompatible Avro schema

Comment: See my answer. It will most probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema Registry enforces certain compatibility rules when new schemas are registered in a subject. Therefore, you need to make sure that the compatibility mode of the subject matches the schema evolution that you are looking for.

---

**Using [`confluent-kafka-python`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/)**

```
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient


sr = SchemaRegistryClient("https://schema-registry-host:8081")

# Options are: 
#   - NONE, FULL, BACKWARD, FORWARD, 
#   - BACKWARD_TRANSITIVE, FORWARD_TRANSITIVE, FULL_TRANSITIVE
sr.set_compatibility("yourSubjectName", "NONE")
```

---

**Using [`python-schema-registry-client`](https://github.com/marcosschroh/python-schema-registry-client/#confluent_kafka.schema_registry.SchemaRegistryClient.set_compatibility)**

```
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient


sr = SchemaRegistryClient("https://schema-registry-host:8081")
sr.update_compatibility(level="NONE", subject="yourSubjectName")
```

---

For a full list of compatibility types, refer to [Confluent Documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html#compatibility-types).

Comment: @1622 I updated my answer. Which library are you using?

Comment: It still throws error, Exception: Incompatible Avro schema. I am using schema_registry.client library. Also its not recommended to use level = "NONE", I have given, sr.update_compatibility(level="FULL", subject="yourSubjectName"), but it still showing error.

Comment: I added default value, along with FULL compatibility mode and it worked. Thanks :)